# Reduced structure of the set of Hermitian matrices with multiple eigenvalues

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra

Let $S \subset \operatorname{Herm}(n)$ be the set of $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices with multiple eigenvalues (say, “degenerated” matrices). $S$ is a real algebraic variety in the real vector space $ \operatorname{Herm}(n)$. In fact, $S$ is the zero set of the discriminant $d$ of the characteristic polynomial. However, the principal ideal $(d)$ is not the reduced structure of $S$.

**Question:** How can we provide the reduced structure of $S$ globally or locally?

**Details:** A reference is [Arnold - Remarks on eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Hermitian matrices, berry phase, adiabatic connections and quantum Hall effect](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01614072). We can see in different ways that $(d)$ is not the reduced structure.

1. The codimension of $S$ is 3, while only 1 equation defines it.
2. We can take the complexification of $ \operatorname{Herm}(n)$: choose a real basis and consider the linear combinations with complex coefficients. The complexification is the space of all $n \times n$ matrices, and the zero locus $S_{\mathbb{C}}$ of the complexification $d_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $d$ has codimension 1. It contains every matrix with multiple eigenvalues.
3. In the case of traceless $2 \times 2$ Hermitian matrices we can use the Pauli basis, and the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of $H=x \sigma_x+y \sigma_y+ z \sigma_z $ is $d(H)=x^2+y^2+z^2$. Its zero locus has only one point (the origin), whose reduced structure is provided by the ideal generated by $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Comment: Consider the set $T$ of complex diagonalizable matrices with multiple eigenvalues. Its (complex) codimension in the space of all $n \times n$ complex matrices seems to be 3. Therefore, instead of $S_{\mathbb{C}}$, $T$ is a good candidate for the ''practical'' complexification of $S$, in the sense that the reduced structure of $S$ is the reduced structure of $T$.